# Install LetsEncrypt SSL on multiple docker apps using the same domain

Tags: docker, containers, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I have deployed multiple docker containers on my CentOS machine and managing them with portainer.
containers are accessible via the same domain e.g.

```
container 1: example.com:80
container 2: example.com:6666
container 3: example.com:5083
```

and so on..
Now I want to use LetsEncrypt SSL for all of my container apps using the same domain (without subdomains).

I have been using nginxproxymanager (container app) to do my reverse proxy settings. Right now I am only able to use only one container (running on port 80) with SSL.

I am new to docker stuff and need help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.